# Why undereferenced pointer have diffrent sizeof than dereferenced - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

So here is my code:

```
cout << "The size of an integer is " << sizeof(int) << endl;
cout << "The size of a double is " << sizeof(double) << endl;
cout << "The size of a string is " << sizeof(string) << endl;
int num = 1234;
cout << "The size of a num is " << sizeof(num) << endl;
int *pnum = &num;
cout << "The size of a pointer pnum is " << sizeof(pnum) << endl;
cout << "The size of a value pointed at by pnum is " << sizeof(*pnum) << endl;
return 0;
```

Im confused by this chunk of code because output of this is:

```
The size of an integer is 4
The size of a double is 8
The size of a string is 40
The size of a num is 4
The size of a pointer pnum is 8
The size of a value pointed at by pnum is 4
```

I think size of a pointer pnum should be the same like value pointed at by pnum because Im watching a tutorial "Programming C++" and in this tutorial they are the same. Can someone explain why they arent the same in my program?

Comment: Because the underlying datatypes have different sizes?

Comment: Let me guess, you're on a 64-bit system? Then pointers are usually 64 bits, while `int` still is 32 bits.

Comment: In the tutorial its just a coincidence that `int` is the same size as `int*`. The sizes vary from system to system.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(pnum)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(int*)`, number of bytes needed to represent a pointer to the int value. Such pointer takes 64 bits at 64-bite system, which is 8 bytes as shown in your code output.

At the same time, `sizeof(*pnum)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(int)`, since `*pnum` has type `int`. This type usualy is 32-bits long, which gives us 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> and in this tutorial they are the same:

the reason could be that for that specific machine (like my own 32 bit machine) sizeof(int) = sizeof(int*) = 4.

The reason you get different results is that `*pnum` is the pointee of `pnum` which is an int (4 bytes on your machine) and `pnum` itself is a pointer (8 bytes on your machine)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I started program in 32 bit machine mode and result is similar to this in tutorial.

Comment: @slayerr297 So did the tutorial actually say that the values are supposed to be the same?  If so, get another tutoriral, as the one you're watching now is wrong.